# How to read string message from ViewBag to Javascript object?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I have this action method which return error message and it did:

```
var content = responsePost.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyAPIResponse>(content);
ViewBag.Message = model.message;
```

In my Razor view page, I try to read it with the following code:

```
@{ 
    var jss = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var userInfoJson = jss.Serialize(ViewBag.Message);
}
<script>
    var errors = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(userInfoJson)');
    $(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < errors.Count; i++)
    {

    }
});
</script>
```

But the output rendered back is:

```
<script>
    var errors = JSON.parse('"[\"Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character. Passwords must have at least one lowercase (\u0027a\u0027-\u0027z\u0027). Passwords must have at least one uppercase (\u0027A\u0027-\u0027Z\u0027).\"]"');
    $(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < errors.Count; i++)
    {

    }
});
</script>
```

I am using C# MVC Razor for the UI and in my API is Identity for the password policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the controller, just set the object in the bag:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var errors = new[] { "error1", "error2" };
    ViewBag.Errors = errors;
    return View();
}
```

Then in view serialize and use it:

```
<script>
    var errors = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.Errors))
    errors.forEach(item => { alert(item);});
</script>
```

Note:

- In case you don't have an array in the bag, for example `ViewBag.Errors = "error1"`, then don't use `forEach`, use `alert(errors);`
- `JSON.parse` is unnecessary in this case. You are not receiving a string from server, you are rendering the html content and javascripts in the response.